# Implication of "android:process" when defining services or receivers

Tags: android, synchronization, android-service

I am looking into more insight of the attribute `android:process` when defined in a `service` or `receiver` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

This is the quote from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#proc):

> **android:process**
>
> The name of the process where the service is to run. Normally, all components of an application run in the default process created for the application. It has the same name as the application package. The  element's process attribute can set a different default for all components. But component can override the default with its own process attribute, allowing you to spread your application across multiple processes.
>
> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed and the service runs in that process. If the process name begins with a lowercase character, the service will run in a global process of that name, provided that it has permission to do so. This allows components in different applications to share a process, reducing resource usage.

When following various examples on how to write a sync service and also a receiver those samples typically contain manifest definitions with a separate `android:process` name.

Here is a sample, where a receiver and a service are defined (*:remote* and *:sync*)

```
<receiver android:name="myapp.backgroundAnalysis.BackgroundAlaramReceiver"
        android:process=":remote"
        >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
</intent-filter>
```

```
<service
    android:name="myapp.backgroundCloudSync.SyncService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:process=":sync">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
    </intent-filter>
    ...
</service>
```

What would actually happen if I omit the `android:process` from both? I understand that they will be run in the default process, where also everything else runs (Main, Threads?, etc.) but will this have an impact on the behaviour of the receiver and SyncService?

Can this impact the applications' behaviour when running or could the receiver interfere with the sync? I am aware than a service will be run on the main thread but will something stall or only delay when code is scheduled to run on the main thread?

*(The background of this question is linked to an issue that I need to run sync operations on some shared resource from various entities (main application, receiver and SyncAdapter) but the shared resource cannot work in multi-process environments, therefore I am trying to understand implications of possible workarounds or solutions)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will this have an impact on the behaviour of the receiver and SyncService?

Not directly.

> Can this impact the applications' behaviour when running

Thread safety becomes a bit more of an issue with everything in one process. OTOH, that can be a lot easier than coordinating work in 2+ processes such that one process does not stomp on the work of the other process.

> I am aware than a service will be run on the main thread

The lifecycle methods of a service (e.g., `onStartCommand()`) will run on the main application thread; your business logic should run on background threads. You have to do that regardless of whether everything is in one process or split between processes.

> will something stall or only delay when code is scheduled to run on the main thread?

If your service runs code on the main application thread, it will block everything else on that thread while that code runs. That is why services always use background threads.

Depending on how you are synchronizing access to shared objects, service code running on a background thread could lock access to those shared objects and therefore stall UI code that tries accessing those objects. That's why we try to organize our code to avoid blocking calls from the UI on such objects, such as by using reactive options (`LiveData`, RxJava, etc.).

Comment: Could you elaborate a but more on "That is why services always use background threads", I do need to manually spin off a separate thread or use a JobScheduler when my services has been triggered because there is nothing in a service that does this automatically?

Comment: @Samuel: Sorry, but I am having difficulty understanding your question. Some specialized types of service offer a background thread for you to use.  For example, `IntentService` and `JobIntentService` will run `onHandleIntent()` on a background thread. However, `onStartJob()` of a `JobService` is *not* called on a background thread, as is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService).

Comment: Sorry, I had to simply read more documents, while `onCreate` is called on the main thread I was unsure whether I had to manually create some background operation by myself but when I understand services correctly (in the context of sync adapters for instance) doing work in `onPerformSync` will already be done in a background thread so all I have to do is perform my work and not concern myself with how to start a background operation at this point.